# Finiteness of solutions to polynomial equations.

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, polynomials, algebraic-topology

I am working on proving that for all functions from $f:\mathbb{R}_{Zariski}\to \mathbb{R}$, $\{x|f(x)=c\}$ is constant.

Since the only continuous functions in the Zarski topology are polynomials, I can reduce this problem to a simpler one. That is, given a polynomial with real coefficients, $f(x)$, I want to show that $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, $\{x|f(x)=c\}$ is finite.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x)$ is a non constant polynomial , then $g(x)=f(x)-c$ is also. Thus, $\{x|f(x)=c\}$ is finite is equivalent to $\{x|g(x)=0\}$ is finite. But the last is true by the Algebra Fundamental Theorem.

On the other hand, constant polynomial $f(x)=c$ doesn't satisfies $\{x|f(x)=c\}$ is finite.